# Dynamically set Template filename parameter in Codepipeline clouformation Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I've created a Codepipeline that is triggered by a github source repository containing multiple cloudformation templates. I've then added a stage configured with a Cloudformation action to deploy a specific template.
I want to be able to dynamically set the filename parameter inside this Cloudformation Action, so I can reuse the same pipeline to deploy several different templates.

I've figured out I can use cloudformation variables in place of this parameter, but there is no way to set those variable before run the pipeline.
I want to avoid replicate the same pipeline just for a single parameter.